# adding reversed columns to dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Trying to add a reversed column to a data frame, but it just adds in normal order. For me, it looks like it is just following the index of the dataframe. Is it possible to reorder the index?

```
df_reversed = df['Buy'].iloc[::-1]
Data["newColumn"] = df_reversed
```

[Image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIZz2.png)

[Image of df_reversed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhOyp.png)

[This is how I want the output to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHMUd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight modification from @Chicodelarose, you can reverse just the values and get the result you want as follows:

```py
data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df["calories_reversed"] = df["calories"].values[::-1]
print(df)
```

Output will be:

```py
   calories  duration
0       420        50
1       380        40
2       390        45

   calories  duration  calories_reversed
0       420        50                390
1       380        40                380
2       390        45                420
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `reset_index` before assigning the values to the new column so that they are added to the data frame in reverse order:

Example:

```
data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df["calories_reversed"] = df["calories"][::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   calories  duration
0       420        50
1       380        40
2       390        45

   calories  duration  calories_reversed
0       420        50                390
1       380        40                380
2       390        45                420
```